# OOP and object parametrization

Tags: oop, architecture, parameter-passing

I am supposed to develop a program, which will heavily depend on input data at runtime (data for initialization, read from XML) and I would like to ask for good OOP practice regarding object/architecture design.

**Situation**

I have the following objects, *object_A, object_B, object_C*, each of them has a specified objective.

*object_A* = evaluation of equations, requires input, produces output

*object_B* = evaluation of equations, requires input, produces output

*object_C* = requires data from *object_A and object_B* as input, produces output

Then there is *object_D*, which passes the data and calls functions among these *objects_A/B/C*.

---

There are 2 ways to tackle this situation that I know of :

**a) Inheritance**

*object_D* inherits from *object_A, object_B, object_C*. Data are passed by appointing appropriate structures in *objects_A/_B/_C* using "this->", virtual functions in *objects_A/_B/_C* can then call back to *object_D*.

- hierarchical approach
- objects are concealed
- difficult to parametrize the *object_A/_B/_C* (parameters need to travel all the way up in the hierarchy to base classes)

**b) Passing pointers**

Create *object_A/_B/_C*, by passing parameters in constructor. Then pass pointers of these objects to constructor of *object_D*.

- no information hiding, all objects are visible
- hierarchy might be unclear, especially when there are more levels
- easy to pass initialization parameters

---

**Question**
What is an appropriate way of handling software architecture, where many objects require passing initialization parameters at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is broad and can have more than one good answer. However, I think your scenario can be solved in one of two ways:

1. Eventing: Instead of tightly coupling your classes using inheritance, you can use events. For instance when Object A finishes processing it raise an event called 'ClassAFinished'. Then you have to create an event handler for ClassAFinish Event that will in turns pass objectA's output to other objects that rely on Object A output.

   2. Second way is Chain of Responsibility design pattern. Since your question is related to OOP I think it's reasonable to use this design pattern. In a nutshell Chain of Responsibility is a design pattern that you use it when you have a series (chain) of objects, each of which will do specific processing (responsibility), but each one of them can't begin processing until it received data from the previous object. When it finishes processing it'll send its output to the next object and so forth.

These are 2 main ideas that I wanted to share with you.